# Can't send PHP $var=file_get_contents('path') variable to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

This is my javascript function.

```
<script>
    function output($file_name, $content)
    {
     document.getElementById("content_title").innerHTML="    "+$file_name;
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=" "+$content; 
    }
</script>
```

This is my PHP code;

```
<?php
$dir = "img_png";
$files = scandir($dir);
$dir_length = count($files);
?>
```

This is the second part of my PHP code (with problem); Problem: When $content="any string"; everything works properly, but when $content=file_get_contents('file'); my triggered function doesn't change any .innerHTML elements at all.

```
<?php
for ($i=2;$i<$dir_length;$i++){
$title=explode(".png", $files[$i]);
$content=file_get_contents('./content_txt/tv.txt');
echo "<td><button id='button' class='button' onClick=\"output('", $title[0],"";
echo "', '", $content,"";
echo "')\"><img src=\"/img_png/", $files[$i], "\"></img></button></td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the file path is right? Check if file_get_contents doesn't return false.

Comment: as dreamstate said: check path - you can check `current working directory` with [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: If I echo $content; anywhere, I get file content as output on my web. So path is right.

Comment: Why are you calling file_get_contents within the loop? What file-content are you giving exactly?

Comment: You are using commas to concatenate strings and not dots.

Comment: This is for linking my fixed buttons to title and content. Idea is to create img.png's in fixed folder. Then by pressing img.png you trigger js function which takes img name before .png extension. Then sends it to $title variable and outputs $content=file.txt with the same name. Basically img.png name controls title and content. Loop is for running through all images.

Comment: $content should be same output within each loop because your fetching the same data each iteration. Can you show us some rows of tv.txt so we could try to figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Start solving your issue with this** (use dots instead of commas to concatenate strings)

```
<?php
for ($i=2;$i<$dir_length;$i++){
    $title=explode(".png", $files[$i]);
    $content=file_get_contents('./content_txt/tv.txt');
    echo "<td><button id='button' class='button' onClick=\"output('" . $title[0];
    echo "', '" . $content;
    echo "')\"><img src=\"/img_png/" . $files[$i] . "\"></img></button></td>";
}
?>
```

Also I would set `$content-variable` outside the loop and skip the end-tag (it doesn't make any difference because `</img>` is not used):

**Also encode your data when sending from php (with urlencode)**

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents('./content_txt/tv.txt');
for ($i=2;$i<$dir_length;$i++){
    $title=explode(".png", $files[$i]);
    echo "<td><button id='button' class='button' onClick=\"output('" . $title[0];
    echo "', '" . urlencode($content);
    echo "')\"><img src=\"/img_png/" . $files[$i] . "\"></button></td>";
}
?>
```

**In your javascript you have to decode the content:**

```
function output($file_name, $content)
{
    $content = decodeURI($content);
    document.getElementById("content_title").innerHTML="    "+$file_name;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=" "+$content; 
}
```

Comment: It's really better way to concatenate, but still this doesn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: @helpmepls - You have to encode and decode your info as well. (In your case because file contained ") It's always a good practice to do that no matter what the data is right now. It could be changed and then your code might not work. See updated answer. My guess is that your javascript-function didn't even execute when using get_contents? Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I wont be able to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @helpmepls - you're welcome. Glad to help. You really should do the same thing for $title-variable because that is dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your file contents may contain line breaks or special characters that need escaping in JS, you will need to escape special characters before passing the string to the javascript function.

Comment: tv.txt file contains ==>> "tvvvvvv";

Answer (score 0):

`"tvvvvvv";`

I suppose you copy-paste that string from PHP to `tv.txt`

Remove `"` and `;` - you don't need it in file.

And `"` is your problem in javascript.

Comment: That's a way of way of solving it right now, but it wouldn't be "future-proof". What if someone added " in the tv.txt at some point?

Comment: You are right. I assumed that SO (as beginner) copied string from PHP to file with `"` and `;` - so this is answer only for question why string assigned directly to variable works fine but string readed from file doesn't. SO copied too much.